# How to group by consecutive rows in a R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with columns TimeStamp, Type, Value in time series data. Type refers to whether it is a peak or valley. I want to:

Group all data by consecutive types
For groups of "peak" type I want to select the highest 
For groups if "valley" type I want to select the lowest
Filter the dataframe by these highest/lowest 
Expectation: I would have a dataframe that alternated each row between the highest peak and lowest valley.

The only way I know how to do this is by using a for loop and then adding consecutive values into a vector and then getting the max, then shoving this in a new dataframe and so on.

For those who know python, this is what I did in that (I need to transfer my code to R though):

```
segmentation['min_v'] = segmentation.groupby( segmentation.pv_type.ne(segmentation.pv_type.shift()).cumsum() ).price.transform(min)
segmentation['max_p'] = segmentation.groupby( segmentation.segmentation.pv_type.ne(segmentation.pv_type.shift()).cumsum() ).price.transform(max)
```

EDIT

Sample data set:

```
types <- c('peak', 'peak', 'valley', 'peak', 'valley', 'valley', 'valley')
values <- c(1.01,   1.00,    0.4,     1.2,     0.3,      0.1,      0.2)
segmentation <- data.frame(types, values)
segmentation

expectedTypes <- c('peak', 'valley', 'peak', 'valley')
expectedValues <- c(1.00, 0.4, 1.2, 0.1 )
expectedResult <- data.frame(expectedTypes, expectedValues)
expectedResult
```

I dont know a better way to generate the data.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code & libraries used, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: "The only way I know how to do this is by using a for loop"
I am new to R, i am happy to use a library but I dont know any. I have added a sample data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `R`, an implementation using `dplyr` would be to take the cumulative sum of the logical comparison between the 'pv_type' and the `lag` of 'pv_type' as a grouping column and then get the `min` and `max` of 'price' as two new columns

```
library(dplyr)
segmentation %>%
       group_by(pv_type_group = cumsum(pv_type != lag(pv_type,
                 default = first(pv_type))) %>%
       mutate(min_v = min(price), max_p = max(price))
```

#### Update

With the OP's example, the expected output is `summarise`d, so we use `summarise` instead of `mutate`.  Also, used `rleid` (from `data.table`) instead of the logical cumulative sum

```
library(data.table)
segmentation %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(types)) %>% 
    summarise(types = first(types), expectedvalues = min(values)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  types  expectedvalues
# <fct>           <dbl>
#1 peak              1  
#2 valley            0.4
#3 peak              1.2
#4 valley            0.1
```

Comment: What does %>% do/mean?

Comment: @user2330270  It is chan operator which connects the lhs output to be used for futher processing

Comment: There are many people who don't have grasp in both languages at the same time.  By downvoting, it is preventing people to respond to code conversion questions and there by reducing the value.  It is a true that the OP didn't provide a reproducible example, but the code conversion doesn't really require that

Comment: ok thanks, having a test of your answer now

Comment: @user2330270  I updated the answer based on your example/expected

Comment: first one didnt work but second one does, thanks a lot. Time to try understand it :D

Comment: @user2330270  Second one is summarised output.  In the python, you were `transform`ing and creating a new column.  Also, the column names were ddifferent in example